# Converting an HTML Attribute to Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm having trouble with converting an HTML-data attribute to a Javascript Object.

Here is what I do:

The Attribute looks like:

```
<a id="stringObj" data-string="{'Foo':'Bar'}">Some A-Tag</a>
```

In Javascript / JQuery I do as followed:

```
var obj = $("#stringObj").data('string').replace(/'/g,"\"");
obj = JSON.stringify(obj);
obj = JSON.parse(obj);
```

I of just used the JSON.stringify method for clean results, but it doesn't really matter. I also tried "eval" on the result but it keeps beeing a "string" on `console.log(typeof obj)` test.

How do I get an object from the attribute so I could use it like `alert(obj.Foo);`?

Comment: Your quotes are wrong. Check out my answer. You have to have a valid JSON...

Answer (score 3):

When you are using `jQuery.data()`, it will be returning it as an object by default, when you use **valid JSON**. If possible, please try to swap the `"` and `'`.

```js
$(function() {
  var data = $("#stringObj").data("string");
  console.log(typeof data);
  console.log(data.Foo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="stringObj" data-string='{"Foo": "Bar"}'>Some A-Tag</a>
```

If you can't change the HTML code for some reason (can't swap the `'` and `"`), use the following snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  var data = $("#stringObj").data("string").replace(/'/g, '"');
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(typeof data);
  console.log(data.Foo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="stringObj" data-string="{'Foo': 'Bar'}">Some A-Tag</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/NzBvYZ

```
var obj = $("#stringObj").data('string').replace(/'/g,"\"");
obj = JSON.parse(obj);
alert(obj.Foo);
```

Comment: There's a better method... `:)` Swap the quotes... Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it **without jQuery**:

```
var stringAttr = document.getElementById("stringObj").dataset.string.replace(/'/g,"\"");
var myObj = JSON.parse(stringAttr);
console.log(myObj.Foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the JSON.stringify and it worked for now.
Of course I tested it a several times before with no success but it does work for some reason :D - thank you guys.